# Set a column value based on other column value on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table contains 2 columns named Id ( IDENTITY(1,1)) and OriginalId

When we newly add an entity, OriginalId always equals to Id

To do that, I must write this stupid code

```
  MyClass obj = new MyClass()
  _repo.Add(obj);
  obj.OriginalId = obj.Id;
  _repo.Update(obj)
```

This one need to write to database 2 times . Is there any way to make it write one time only to have OriginalId = Id
Regards,

Comment: What is `class.Id`? Shouldn't it be `obj.id`?

Comment: Create a function to do it one time. `YourFunction(class.id)` Coding need more patient if you need to have a better result.

Comment: Create an insert trigger on your SQL table, which will update `OriginalId` value every time when new data inserted.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: you are correct. Sorry for my typo
@
reds: I don't get your point. Could you please make it clearer ?

@ SeM: Thank you for your suggestion. I would like to find the way to resolve it in EF before using trigger.

Comment: Try with calculated fields :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table

Comment: You can write SQL query manually: `context.Database.SqlQuery("INSERT... UPDATE...")`

Answer (score 3):

if your `obj.id` is auto-increment, just try to get the latest `id` in `_repo` before adding your new `obj` to the repository. Do something like this:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();

var latestId = _repo.GetLatestId();
obj.OriginalId = ++latestId;

_repo.Add(obj);
```

However, If you don't want to access the repository two times, you need to change your table scheme. Your `id` should not be auto-increment and you need to generate the `id` by yourself or you can use [Guid.NewGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to generate a unique `id`. In this case, try something like this:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();

obj.id = Guid.NewGuid();
obj.OriginalId = obj.id;

_repo.Add(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution
However, this one still access database 2 times ( one to get lastestId, one to add the data)

Moreover, if the last record ( let say Id = 1000) is deleted. then the new last record has Id = 999. If we use your solution, Id will be 1001 and OriginalId will be 1000
Regards,

Comment: @wraith That's true, but I think you have no choice. however in this solution you don't need to update your whole object (that has high performance cost) and you just get an integer value (that has low performance cost). Then you add your whole object to the repository.

Comment: @wraith you still have other two solutions by `Masoud Darvishian`. you can make auto increment false and add Id by yourself.  for both. then you won't face that issue. and using `GUID` is also the best Solution.